# Luigi to run pandas scripts daily?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, luigi

I have a bunch of python files which do the end-to-end file processing for various data sources.

For example, survey.py would read the file with pandas, add columns, rename stuff, do some calculations, and then save the modified file back to disk.

driver.py would follow the same process for that file, etc. This same structure is happening for dozens of files.

I then have a file called process_all which basically just runs each python file in a certain order (some files are dependent on others). Upon further research, I stumbled upon a library called luigi which seems like it completes this same task more robustly if I need to scale.

Question: Do I continue to write separate .py files to process data, or do I put all of those things within my classes in luigi? I assume there is one class per raw file I will be processing, correct?

Or do I write out all of the processing steps within the luigi class, like the CleanDriver class below? This seems like it will become super lengthy since a lot of these individual code files are 20-50 lines each and there are dozens.

```
class CleanSurvey(luigi.Task):
    date_interval = luigi.DateIntervalParameter()

    def run(self):
        os.system('../py_files/run_ftp.py')

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(path + 'test_survey.csv')

class CleanDriver(luigi.Task):
    date_interval = luigi.DateIntervalParameter()

    def run(self):
        df = pd.read_csv('../file.csv')
        df['col5'] = do stuff
        df.rename(columns={:}, inplace=True)

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(path + 'test_driver.csv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi.run
```

Comment: Oh, by the way. I have literally never used a Class before in any of my code so I am not used to it honestly.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you to learn [object orientation in Python](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/) before getting into this. It will helpful to work with Luigi.

Luigi indeed helps by helping out creating data processing pipelines. The pipelines are made of tasks. (That's roughly a class per step).

With respect to your question about how to wrap those steps into classes. YMMV. I like to have my Luigi classes following the Single responsibility principle. That is each tasks does one thing, but right. It is also easier to debug in the future and make changes.

Finally in the example you mentioned you have classes without `requires()`. This function is important because it allows you to give the output of one task to the another one, creating a proper dependency tree.

Comment: Thanks, I read through the link. I am very used to reading a file into memory (pandas) and then doing things to it like adding/removing/renaming columns, performing calculations, aggregating or joining data, etc. All of these things need to be done while the file is still in memory, and it would be different for each file. Have you come across any tutorials for using classes to clean up files or do a lot of file IO operations? Some things seem like they need to be explicit (like renaming id_col on one file to employee_id, renaming id_col on another file to customer_id, etc.)

Comment: I usually split the pipeline itself and the business logic, So I'd recommend you to have another python file with `do_stuff()` function, then import it and run within the luigi task. This way you won't confuse data pipe logic and business logic, and will keep task as possible.